# How to fill gaps with random values in pandas dataframe based on a time column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe, this data comes from an IoT Sensor which is setup to send data every 20 minutes.

```
eui BatV    TempC_DS    TempC_SHT   EventEnqueuedUtcTime    id  _rid    _self   _etag   _attachments    _ts
0   A8404181D1822E6B    3.007   22.06   22.32   2021-02-25T11:05:58.5410000Z    9e557ae0-adf6-48b7-8f44-5794f441eb09    AqMcAMV7-mIBAAAAAAAAAA==    dbs/AqMcAA==/colls/AqMcAMV7-mI=/docs/AqMcAMV7-...   "4f009de9-0000-0d00-0000-6037856c0000"  attachments/    1614251372
1   A8404181D1822E6B    3.007   22.12   22.35   2021-02-25T11:25:58.2880000Z    72ff84c0-4591-4f2d-bedb-b389cf56819c    AqMcAMV7-mICAAAAAAAAAA==    dbs/AqMcAA==/colls/AqMcAMV7-mI=/docs/AqMcAMV7-...   "5000cf7c-0000-0d00-0000-60378a470000"  attachments/    1614252615
2   A8404181D1822E6B    3.007   22.18   22.40   2021-02-25T11:45:58.2800000Z    d2f9a0fd-e29a-42a1-a639-2c467a4d7f71    AqMcAMV7-mIDAAAAAAAAAA==    dbs/AqMcAA==/colls/AqMcAMV7-mI=/docs/AqMcAMV7-...   "5100900d-0000-0d00-0000-60378ef20000"  attachments/    1614253810
3   A8404181D1822E6B    3.007   22.25   22.45   2021-02-25T12:05:58.3790000Z    6600af86-5055-44d3-8503-92981431c39f    AqMcAMV7-mIEAAAAAAAAAA==    dbs/AqMcAA==/colls/AqMcAMV7-mI=/docs/AqMcAMV7-...   "510032ce-0000-0d00-0000-603794d60000"  attachments/    1614255318
```

You can see the 20 min gaps in the column EventEnqueuedUtcTime

My task is to create rows between each reading to represent 1 minute readinggs intead of 20.

so if at 10:00 AM the temperature was 22.06
and at 10:20 AM the temperature was 22.12

Then I should add rows at
10:01
10:02
10:03
etc
with random values which are not far from this range.

Comment: Do you really want *random* values or could linear interpolation be an option? on any other pandas builtin interpolation method?

Comment: thats a great idea too!

Comment: [`df.resample('1Min')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) might be helpful here.

Comment: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'RangeIndex'

Comment: @LuisValencia Set `EventEnqueuedUtcTime` as index then try it.

Comment: got this:  Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've taken the following approach:

I did not have the original dataframe, so constructed actual datetime objects from the strings and rounding the output to minutes:

```
df['EventEnqueuedUtcTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['EventEnqueuedUtcTime']).round('min')
```

Or for older version than the most recent version to date (rounds down as opposed to rounding):

```
df['EventEnqueuedUtcTime'] = pd.to_da`tetime(df['EventEnqueuedUtcTime'].apply(lambda x: x[:10]+' '+x[11:16]))
```

Then set is as index:

```
df = df.set_index('EventEnqueuedUtcTime')
```

Then resample the index on minute basis:

```
df.resample('T').interpolate()
```

I've used interpolate as an example, which would interpolate any numerical value. For the text fields you could either fill then using the last known value or create your own logic and use the apply method instead of interpolate.

You can return to the original setup of df by resetting the index.

Comment: I got this error on the first line: TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)

Comment: Think that is a pandas version issue. Works well in the most recent version. You can also do the following (rounds down as opposed to rounding ):  df['EventEnqueuedUtcTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['EventEnqueuedUtcTime'].apply(lambda x: x[:10]+' '+x[11:16])). Also edited the answer

Comment: thank you, this works almost perfect, the only issue I am having is that the eui column in the new rows is NaN, and thats my sensor id which needs to be filled for the gaps too

Comment: Just use df['eui'] = df['eui'].fillna(method='ffill') to fill the blanks